# Multicast MAC using destination MACs

Tags: switch, switching, mac-address, switching-modes

I am working on a routing algorithm which involves multicasts, my question is: Is there a possible way to convert a list of MAC addresses to a single multicast MAC address for configuration purposes?
For now I am treating multicasts as unicasts with same vlan and stream ID to multiple destinations.

Comment: there is such thing as multicast MAC address. if you need more information you can check how OSPF AllSPFRouters and AllDRRouters addresses are mapped to multicast MACs.

Comment: Can you expand on your question?  Routing only takes place at layer 3, so it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A MAC address has no relationship to a different MAC address, so there is no "converting." You can convert a multicast IP address to a multicast MAC address, but unicast MAC addresses are unicast, and multicast MAC addresses are multicast, based on the IP address.

Comment: Please refer to the comment on @Zac67 's post. Thank you.

Comment: You may want to read the book *Interdomain Multicast Routing* which also covers most of the basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possible way to convert a list of MAC addresses to a single multicast MAC address?

No. That's not the way multicast works.

On L2, any MAC address that has the I/G bit set (the first octet's least significant bit) is a multicast address. Any host within the broadcast domain can choose to receive or to ignore it.

For the sender there's no difference, so treating multicast and unicast alike is OK.

Things change a bit with L3 multicast (IGMP) - which may be prunable or routable - but you'll need to provide more details on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. I am working on an algorithm that finds paths to a specific src-des pair in a network, but some of my flows are multicast so instead of providing a single MAC address of the destination I need a Multicast MAC address which includes all the destinations for a single multicast. 
what I have is a list of MACs for my destinations but I am unsure as to how to come up with these multicast mac addresses. 
I am using all this to have a switch configuration platform and this is just a small part of it. I'm coding on python.

Comment: To put it simply:  How should one create the multicast MAC address for a group of receivers

Comment: You can get an OUI from IEEE ([here](https://standards.ieee.org/products-services/regauth/oui36/index.html)) or use a Locally Administered Address (LAA) by setting the MAC's U/L bit. Then your receivers just need to listen to that address. Also, I think you're just reinventing the wheel (*find paths to a specific src-des pair*). It might be useful to give us more details on your task so we could suggest a compatible and efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, yes. But I don't know any commercial routers that would do it. It's easy enough to trick a Linux system into do it.

What you're asking for is unicast-to-multicast conversion. I've seen the reverse (multicast-to-unicast) in wireless access points. (broadcast, and thus multicast, is sent at *basic rate* which is always super slow.) But I don't think that's actually what you *want*. The way multicast works, **any** number of sources can send to the same group, and anyone can join that group and see those messages. If multicast routing is working, they don't even have to be in the same broadcast domain / subnet.